Iframe not loading on a CMS page
We are trying to embed a Magento 2 website's page on another Magento CMS page using iframe, but the iframe is not working.
When I checked the browser console I found an error.

This is my csp_whilist.xml file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="frame-ancestors">
            <values>
                <value id="local-flem***" type="host">http://local-old-flem***.com/</value>
                <value id="self" type="host">self</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="local-flem***" type="host">http://local-old-flem***.com/</value>
                <value id="self" type="host">self</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
       </policies>
</csp_whitelist>


share the code into question what you try?

Can you try once other magento site's domain in CSP frame-src or check the server side X-Frame-Options.

@SanjayJethva I tried, but it did not work.

@SanjayJethva   I have added the csp_whitelist.xml file , please check and let you know what do you think about it

@Dhiren Vasoya i have added the code.

@RJ I do not found your iframe code into question.
